# What is the collective nature of gravity?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

My understanding is that gravity is the interaction between all objects with mass. This applies to every single particle that has mass, regardless of size. We know that bodies with very large masses exert a stronger force than bodies with smaller masses. But how does this work on the microscopic scale? The Earth, for example, is just a huge collection of atoms. Doesn't each one pull everything around it due to its mass? Wouldn't that mean that the force produced by each atom / subatomic particle cancel with all the others? If I am hypothetically in a little pocket of space deep within the Earth (say, a meter away from the Earth's core), does gravity still affect me in the same manner, since technically it's now just a small amount of matter "beneath" me? Or would I be pulled upwards, because there is now so much matter directly "above" me (ignoring atmospheric pressure)?

Essentially, my confusion is how gravity behaves when we look at matter as a collection of many particles. It's not very difficult to understand when you think, "Oh, I'm standing on a very heavy object." But when you start to picture it on a smaller scale it stops making sense very quickly!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about gravity inside the Earth. The matter outside pulls you, but it turns out the math works out so that (assuming Earth is a sphere) when you are inside the planet, the effect is the same as if the only matter you feel is at the radius less than where you are standing.  The matter above where you are standing cancels out.   This is called the Shell Theorem.

So the strength of gravity increases with radius squared From infinity to the planet's surface, And then decrease is linearly to zero at the center of the Earth

But overall you have the right idea, that every small piece of matter $dm$ attracts a test mass $m_0$ with a force

$$dF = \frac{Gm_0dm}{r^2}$$

(at least in a Newtonian framework).  The aggregate behavior upon summation depends on the mass distribution.